# How do I catch an exception thrown from ChannelInitializer.initChannel?

Tags: netty

I have a ChannelInitializer in which initChannel can throw an exception. How do I catch this exception? I tried adding exceptionCaught, but get the same result, which is something along the line of:

10:24:02.547 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-0] WARN  io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer - Failed to initialize a channel. Closing: [id: 0x4639a9bd, /127.0.0.1:36004 => /127.0.0.1:6060]
java.lang.Exception: MyException
[stack trace]

For the record, I'm using 5.0.0.Alpha2

Comment: can you share the code of your `initChannel` method? do you know where the exception originates from? i think your only chance for this would be to get this exception out of the channel initialization.

Comment: @Moh-Aw Conceptually, just throw a generic exception from initChannel. Certainly one can wrap the contents of their initChannel in the try/catch form. However, netty is behaving badly by not propagating the Exception through the netty framework. Since ChannelInitializer extends ChannelHandlerAdapter which implements ChannelHandler, one would expect to handle exceptions through exceptionCaught.

Comment: As I interpret this, netty is in a particular situation when calling initChannel, namely setting up the pipeline. If this operation throws, the channel pipeline can be considered being incorrectly set up, in which case it might be the best to close the channel. Better would be to set up the pipeline in a "fail safe" mode, i.e. without the possibility of throwing an exception, and possibly add an initial handler that executes the logic that can throw (if this is possible in your workflow).

Answer (score 0):

ChannelInitializer exception propagation will be added to netty 4.0.29.Final as described in [issue #3780](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/3780)

Answer (score -1):

It seems that netty just logs the exception and triggers nothing. See: https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/5725e804bcfbd0c76e0f11e7911a76970eb06c8c/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/ChannelInitializer.java#L74

You should do your own exception handling in initChannel method.

Comment: ...followed by: `if (!success) { ctx.close(); }` which closes the channel immediately.

Comment: see also the javadoc: `@throws Exception  is thrown if an error occurs. In that case the {@link Channel} will be closed.`

Comment: Yeah but op wants to catch that exception.